# Background knowledge to prove that 'if set S in R is closed and bounded and non-empty, then sup S is in S.'

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am new to Real Analysis and Metric Space.
While searching for proof of this, I found that I am not fully understanding that if the nonempty set S is closed and bounded, then there must exist a subsequence that converges to supS.
I would like to know why the subset S of R must have a subsequence that converges to supS so that supS is in S.
Please help.

Comment: @KevinArlin I'm aware of the theorem. The theorem says that there always exists a convergent subsequence in bounded sequence. However, I just wonder how we could claim that such subsequence converges to supremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha = \sup S$, then for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(\alpha-1/n, \alpha+1/n) \cap S$ is nonempty. Let $a_n \in  (\alpha-1/n, \alpha+1/n) \cap S$ and note $a_n \to \alpha$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence $\alpha \in S$ since $S$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here I propose a sketch of an alternative proof.

If the set $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is bounded and it is not empty, then it admits an infimum and a supremum.

Once it is closed, it contains all of its adherent points.

Given that the infimum and the supremum are adherent points, the result holds.